# iOS7: Is it possible to get a reference to the Control Center

Tags: ios, uibutton, ios7

I currently have a button at the bottom of one of my views that only highlights after a delay due to the `Control Center's` gesture recognizer at the bottom of the screen.

When a button is placed within a scrollview, `delaysContentTouches` must be set to `NO` in order for the button to highlight immediately. However, it doesn't look like the Gesture Recognizer/anything can be accessed related to the Control Center. Because of this, there is no way to set `delaysContentTouches = NO`.

Is it possible/are we allowed to gain access to the Control Center?